# Simple working example using plugin writen in Qt and make it work with NPAPI

Tags: qt, google-chrome, npapi

Can anybody show me simple working example using Qt(export DLL plugin file) and make it work with NPAPI. I want simple example to test it in Google Chrome. Any links, codes ...
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a nice framework called Firebreath for writing cross-platform browser plugins in C++. It comes with plenty of documentation and example projects, so it's easy to get started. As a plus, in addition to NPAPI hosts you pretty much get free support for ActiveX browsers (Internet Explorer) too.

http://www.firebreath.org

Answer (score 4):

Check out the QtBrowserPlugin solution, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/developingplugins.html

There you should find information about writing your own NPAPI plugins.

Update:
I did not realize there was no useful link to the source, it can be found in gitorious at
http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/ to browse online http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtbrowserplugin